# QueryExecutionKernelException: row not defined while creating a node in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have installed neo4j and started with neo4jshell using neo4jShell start command.I have create a graph database and have to load data using .xls or .csv file format files. I am using the below command in the neo4jshell,

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:RT_RISK.csv" AS ROW 
CREATE (:Rt_Risk{risk_id:row.Risk_id,owner:row.owner,
   risk_category: row.Risk_Category, description:row.Description} );"
```

But getting the below error "QueryExecutionKernelException: row not defined".
Kindly Suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You're defining an capital variable in the first line `AS ROW` but use it in lower case letters in l. 2 and 3 `row`.

Identifiers are case sensitive.

Comment: I have tried the below as well.
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:\Users\shifali\Documents\Neo4j\RT__RISK_LOSSEVENT.csv' AS risklossevent CREATE (rle1:RT__RISK_LOSSEVENT{label: risklossevent.label, RiskId:risklossevent.RISK_ID, LossEventId:risklossevent.LOSSEVENT_ID});
It doesn't work